# How the comment section in Facebook or Azure is implemented where we can tag some user using '@' symbol?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm trying to develop a comment box like application, similar to Facebook, using MERN stack. Adding simple comments is not an issue. But how does the tagging mechanism works where we tag some user with '@' symbol?
Do I need to store the comment in MongoDb database as some special structure which makes it easy to display the tagged user in react? Or it is achieved with some different technique?

**Edit**: The question is what roles will the UI and API play, how the code flow will be, and what additional things (eg reference section in comment-document) should be part of the Mongo Database to make this work?

Comment: Note that your question is basically "I want to do X, can someone teach me how to do it" rather than "I wanted to do X, I [searched and researched](/help/how-to-ask) and found possible ways A, B, C, ..., and so I implemented those but I keep running into problems. Here's the [mcve] code I wrote, what I expected it to do, what it does instead, and what I already tried in terms of debugging". As such, this is not the kind of question that Stackoverflow is for: it's not a general help forum, the explanation of [the kind of questions you can ask here](/help/on-topic) is fairly clear on that.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear if you want to know the database semantics or the frontend part as your question is very broad. But here are some pointers;

- Frontend: you can use `onKeyDown` event on a `textarea` to figure out what char was typed. If it was a `@` you can show the user a dropdown of users and reduce that if the user keeps on typing.
- Backend: once submitted, you want to find all the `@user` mentions. This can be done with regex to find everything that starts with a @. E.g e regex like `[\s\.]?@(\w)\s` would give you all the mentions within a sentence. You then would find the user in your database and add a reference to the comment entry in your database.
- Database: once you know the user, you may want to notify the mentioned user, add to inbox etc. There are many different techniques to achieve this and it really depends on your requirements and database of choice and your schema. But generally speaking there are two widely used techniques called `Fan out on Read` or `Fan out on Write`

Comment: A) Database:
    Suppose an User is stored in the MongoDb database with id ObjectId("user-a-id"). In comment section for a post, if the user is tagged, then the nodeJs API should parse the comment add reference to the comment entry in that post (may be front end can pass the user-id to make it easy).

B) UI: To make the tagged user clickable, UI need to read the received comment with references and update it right?